# The NewButton in the header template of the aspxgridview(DevExpress Control)

Tags: gridview

Can I add the NewButton  in the header template of the  aspxgridview(DevExpress Control) to insert a new record to the aspxgridview ?becuase I don't want to add the NewButton in every row in the grid

I would appreciate any help in this

Answer (score 6):

Try this [`link`](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/SearchResults.aspx?searchtext=new%20button&p=T4%7CP5%7C57)

This has been brought up a few times (and answered) on the DevExpress forums.

The crux of the solution is to add a footer template to your grid and then put an html button in the footer with the `OnClick handler set to mygridname.AddNewRow();`

as in...

```
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="grid.AddNewRow();" />
```

Comment: If using a dx:ASPxButton, you'll need to set AutoPostBack="false". See http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q274448.aspx

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question,
I've never seen this done in the header of a GridView (probably because most users wish to keep the column headings that are done in the header). I'm a bit curious about this myself.

I have seen this done in the footer, though. If you'd like to do it that way, here are a few links (with pictures, horray) to get you started:

- http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/98_Adding_a_New_Row_in_GridView.aspx
- http://amitpatriwala.wordpress.com/2008/04/18/inserting-new-row-in-gridview-in-aspnet-20/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/NewRowGridView.aspx
- http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Adding-Dynamic-Rows-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control-with-TextBoxes.aspx

HTH.

Comment: thank you,
but actually I used aspxgridview from devexpress in my application,so do you have any idea how to implement that code in devexpress gridview??

Answer (score 0):

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q357944

I hope this forum will help you

Just Try the below code

> ```
> <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grvParametros" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server" ...>
>     ...
>     <Templates>
>         <Header>
>             <a href="javascript:grid.AddNewRow()">New</a>
>         </Header>
>     </Templates>
> </dx:ASPxGridView>
> ```